# Errors in parsing escaped double quotes with json parsers

Tags: ruby

How would one parse a JSON string like this:

```
"[{\"something\": \"information \"YES\"\", \"next\": \"normal\"}]"
```

I've used both the json gem and the Oj gem but they both run into errors. I've also tried using eval() on it.

I've also tried using different regexes to target the quotes surrounding YES and replacing them with single quotes but I haven't been successful in figuring one out.

Answer (score 3):

The string you posted isn't valid JSON. This would be the non-stringified JSON:

```
[{"something":"information \"YES\"","next":"normal"}]
```

Note that the escaping is still present in the value for `something`.

If you had this JSON as a string, the double-quote escaping depends on the language you're working in. In Ruby, this is what it looks like:

```
"[{\"something\":\"information \\\"YES\\\"\",\"next\":\"normal\"}]"
```

If you use that, you'll be able to parse it just fine:

```
JSON.parse("[{\"something\":\"information \\\"YES\\\"\",\"next\":\"normal\"}]")
#=> [{"something"=>"information \"YES\"", "next"=>"normal"}]
```

Comment: The problem is, I'm getting a string similar to what I posted as a reponse from an external API that I'm using. The majority of responses are valid JSON strings which I can parse, but there's the odd one or two which cannot be parsed due to the problems above. It seems like my only option is to figure out a regex to target the offending double quotes, or to handle the edge cases individually.

Comment: That API is sending you garbage data, so unless you can get them to fix that you're stuck. This is a bug, there is no question about it. Someone has to encode it properly, and hopefilly that responsibility doesn't fall on you because fixing it will be *ugly*.

Comment: @KelvinChan Is the JSON response wrapped in double quotes, or is this a value fragment in a larger JSON object?